# Most Efficient way to Store Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, local-storage

I am currently working on a Swift project and I would like to save permanent user data in the following manner:

> USERNAME 
>   - List of Strings (String array)

This so that when I search for a Username, I am either given a nil return (if the username does not exist), or a list of Strings that I can iterate through. I know of a few methods of saving user data, however, as I am new to Swift, I do not know all methods of permanently save user data. Nor do I know which ones best suit my needs.

Comment: Efficiency of any particular method depends at least partly on volume. How many user names are we talking about, here? How much data will be associated with each?

Comment: @BobWakefield Probably about 1-5 usernames, 8-35 Strings on the string array

Comment: iOS or macOS? Either way there are the usual options - SQLite, Core Data, plist file, or other binary file.

Comment: @rmaddy it's in iOS. And in those can I store data couples? Like a string associated with a string array.

Comment: For such low data quantities, you could just read and write an `NSDictionary`

Comment: @AshleyMills Which is where a plist comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this…

```
let people: [String: [String]] = ["Jim": ["bread", "fruit", "meat"],
              "Alan": ["pears", "peas", "turnip"],
              "Sue": ["cabbage", "rice", "bblueberries"]]

let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last!
let fileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("myfile")

(people as NSDictionary).write(to: fileUrl, atomically: true)
```

and then…

```
let people = NSDictionary(contentsOf: fileUrl) as! [String: [String]]
```

For system urls… https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1407726-urls

`NSDictionary`…
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary?language=swift

Comment: Is this saved permanently? What's an example of a URL? How can you loop through the NSDictionary? Can I automate setting/receiving the data pairs into a function? ex. setValues(username, stringarray), and getArray(username).

Comment: Yes, this is saved permanently. Added some URL details to the answer, You're going to have to go and try some of these things out for yourself. Write some code, than ask more questions if you have problems.